# how to load one to many relation entities in jpa with counts of the child entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, toplink

I get into this issue while working on Spring/Hibernate/JPA.

Here is the outline of my question.

I have OneToMany relationship between student and attendance tables.

Here is how my entities are built:

```
@Entity
class Student{
@Id
private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",
               cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                           CascadeType.REFRESH })
  private List<Attendance> attendances;
}

@Entity
class Attendance{

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
 private Student student;
}
```

Now I want to query all the students and the number of attendances (attendances count).

Here is what i have tried, without any success:

```
select P.id, N from Student s left join s.attendances, IN(s.attendances) as N;
```

The above script is part of a complex named Query and there are others Entities involved too but I am kind of lost on the concept of getting the attendaces count into `N`.

any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this as Hibernate so using HQL you should be able to write:

```
select student.id, count(student.attendances) from Student as student
```